# Using 2 Titles in an embed in Discord.py

Tags: duplicates, discord.py, embed, title

I'm making a discord bot for my server and I want to send 2 links when the user says vote.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

if message.content.startswith (']svote') :
    await message.add_reaction (doubleupemote)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Vote the Server", url="https://top.gg/servers/876028384042426368/vote", color=0x00fa11)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

In here it sends an embed with Vote The Server. Is there any method to add another title to the same embed?

Or any alt way to send

> Vote For Bot

> Vote the server

*I want to insert 2 links to these 2 sentences.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have "two titles" in one embed. You can create a new line in the title with `\n` but you will not be able to post a second link/the titles will only link to one URL.

You can however make a `description` or add a `field`.

**Have a look at the following example code for a description:**

```py
if message.content.startswith (']svote') :
    await message.add_reaction (doubleupemote)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00fa11)
    embed.title = "Links to vote"
    embed.description = "**[Vote for the bot](https://top.gg/) \n [Vote for the server](https://top.gg/)**"
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

**The output:**

[image: Output of the embed]

If you want to have it in a title, you can use the method I mentioned, but it will not be the same output.

**Code for a title that should work:**

```py
embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00fa11)
embed.title = "Vote for the bot: https://top.gg/ \nVote for the server: https://top.gg/"
```

**The output:**

[image: Two "titles" in an embed]